# Why do some studies show a correlation between vegetarian diets and depression?

Tags: health, vegetarian-diet, mental-health

Why is it that many studies have shown a correlation between meatless diets and depression?

A [study](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0165032722010643) published in Journal of Affective Disorders this month (September 2022) found that

> participants who excluded meat from their diet were found to have a higher prevalence of depressive episodes as compared to participants who consumed meat.

The study was limited to Brazil, but it makes me wonder: is this study reproducible everywhere? Is there any causation here?

Why is it that some studies have shown that there is a correlation between meatless diets and depression?

Comment: See also https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/610/how-to-spot-when-a-study-is-sponsored-by-the-meat-industry

Comment: It's important to note that they mention at the top of the paper also "Nutrient deficiencies do not explain this association".
so far the reasons are speculative. but it seems that the depression precedes the diet. So it can be for example as a side-effect of antidepressants that people's appetite changes, or that depressed people are more concerned with animals' suffering